# Calculate average or take in an ArrayList as a parameter to a function

Tags: java, function, arraylist, average

Is there a built-in method to calculate the average of an integer ArrayList?

If not, can I make a function that will do that by taking in the name of the ArrayList and returning its average value?

Comment: none.... yes....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's really simple:

```
// Better use a `List`. It is more generic and it also receives an `ArrayList`.
public static double average(List<Integer> list) {
    // 'average' is undefined if there are no elements in the list.
    if (list == null || list.isEmpty())
        return 0.0;
    // Calculate the summation of the elements in the list
    long sum = 0;
    int n = list.size();
    // Iterating manually is faster than using an enhanced for loop.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += list.get(i);
    // We don't want to perform an integer division, so the cast is mandatory.
    return ((double) sum) / n;
}
```

For even better performance, use `int[]` instead of `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: @esej not necessarily, only if the sum is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE. Just to be sure, I edited my answer to use `long`. Beyond that, I don't think the OP _really_ needs to get to the point of storing the sum in a `BigInteger` just for this.

Comment: I think the correct statement should have been: "this may overflow".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to computer later one more than the average I propose [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) library developed at CERN which supports many statistic functions. See [BinFunctions1D](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/hep/aida/bin/BinFunctions1D.html) and [DoubleMatrix1D](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/DoubleMatrix1D.html).
An alternative (with a recent code basis) may be [commons-math](http://commons.apache.org/math/):

```
DescriptiveStatistics stats = new DescriptiveStatistics();
for( int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
{
    stats.addValue(inputArray[i]);
}
double mean = stats.getMean();
```

Answer (score 2):

Comming soon, using lambda expressions and method references in [JDK 8](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/):

```
DoubleOperator summation = (a, b) -> a + b;
double average = data.mapReduce(Double::valueOf, 0.0,  summation) / data.size();
System.out.println("Avergage : " + average);
```

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. You can simply iterate over the complete list to add all the numbers and simply divide the sum by length of the array list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ['mean'](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/stat/StatUtils.html#mean%28double%5B%5D%29) from the [Apache Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons) library.