# How to calculate average value using List of doubles from database

Tags: android, database, list, average

I am trying to calculate an average value from a list of doubles I get from my database using the method explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10466020/1617602) but it doesn't work. The app crashes probably because of an overflow.

```
private double getAverage() {
        Cursor cursor = db.getMarks(subject);
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            list.add(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_VALUE)));
        }
        if (list.isEmpty())
            return 0.0;

        long sum = 0;
        int n = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sum += list.get(i);
        return ((double) sum) / n;
    }
```

Is there a method to get a working code for calculating the average?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you let the database calculate the average for you? Check out the `avg(X)` function for SQLite [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)

Comment: @JesperB It seems that I can't call this method using the android DatabaseHelper so I don't know what to import to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the exception you get?
if it is indeed overflow, try it like that:

```
private double getAverage() {

    Cursor cursor = db.getMarks(subject);


    int count = cursor.getCount();
    double sum = 0.0;
    if(count == 0){
        cursor.close();
        return sum;
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        sum += cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_VALUE));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return sum / count;
}
```

Comment: I don't get any exception. As soon as the code is called, the screen of the device turns black until the application gets terminated by the user. Your code does not work either

Comment: Gets terminated how? Is it an ANR or crash?

Comment: A crash I think. The user doesn't get a ANR message and the screen stays black until the execution of the application is stopped by the user.

Comment: Is there any print in the logcat indicating what's happening?  how many entries are there in the cursor? if it is alot and you are performing this calculation on the UI thread it might explain it...

Comment: I think that's the problem. In the LogCat it says "The application may be doing too much work on it's main thread." The cursor has only one entry which should not make the thread calculate that much...

Comment: Oh, I see. Without the moveToNext() statement the thread is stuck on an infinite loop. Now it works like a charm. Thank you very much.